# PHP8.3.3 SQL Server driver not loading

Tags: php, windows

I have had PHPv8.0 working on a WIN11 machine.

I downloaded and installed the latest PHPv8.3.3 and removed the old v8.0 installation directory.

I changed all my required IIS settings accordingly.

I downloaded the latest SQLSRVv512 driver package from Microsoft.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#download

I have put the `php_sqlsrv_83_nts_x64.dll` into my `ext` directory
I have ensured the extension directory is set using `extension_dir="./ext"`

My `phpinfo();` is not showing the SQLSRV driver being loaded.

I am confident that I have not modified the 'wrong' `php.ini` file.
I have been using `iisreset` between configuration changes.

Can anyone verify PHPv8.3.3 with that SQLSRV driver build?
Is there a way of trouble shooting extension loading?

Comment: Run PHP via commandline. Explicitly specify the configuration file there and e.g. `-m` or `-i`. If that gives you different info than the above, you haven't configured PHP correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Running the PHP command via the command line resulted in a wealth of information. In particular it highlighted an syntax error with the PHP.ini file that was preventing it from loading.

It had never occurred to me to run PHP from a command line, but the resulting error information was invaluable for identifying and rectifying the issue with the PHP.ini file.

From this point on, testing a PHP install via the command line will be part of my rollout procedure to ensure that errors are picked up and managed correctly.